# Как можно сделать корешок TabControla

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Как можно сделать корешок TabControla вот таким

```
  --------------  
 /           х /  
/             /  
--------------
```

Где "х" кнопка закрыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Painting Your Own Tabs - Second Edition](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition)

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://tech.pro/tutorial/730/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out)  обьясняют про изменение TabControl`a в(WPF), На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170375/) есть статья для winforms. Советую сначала подучить немного WPF, а уже потом изголяться над внешним видом ;)